# Javascript direct confirm() function replacement

Tags: javascript, confirm

I would like to replace the Javascript confirm() function to allow custom buttons instead of Yes/Cancel. I tried searching but all the solutions are event driven such as jquery dialog(where the code does not wait for a response but it is event driven). Does anyone know of a non-event driven solution. It must work in Safari as well as IE (so no vbscript).

Here is sample code in many parts of my system. This is old code and was not designed with event driven windows in mind. I am trying to avoid a rewrite.

```
**


// Wait for users response
if (result>2000) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure this is right?")){

       ... do stuff

    } 
 }
 ... continue with other stuff
 ... lots of other code.

 if (confirm("Did you double check your numbers?")){

       ... do more stuff

 } else {
      ... do something
 }
```

**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like the others have said, this isn't possible. `confirm` is a blocking function - no more script is executed until the user has dismissed the dialog - and you can't simulate that with other methods of Javascript.

A better solution would be to structure your code for asynchronous execution. This is almost always a better idea -- firstly, it lets you decide how your dialogs should look, what buttons there are, etc; and secondly, it doesn't block the user. They might have the important information they need to double-check open in another tab, or elsewhere on the page. With `confirm` they'd have to answer your question before being able to get to either of these places.

Here's a snippet of what the code might look like. There's a lot of blank bits here, but it might put you on the right track:

```
if (result>2000) {
    displayConfirm("Are you sure this is right?", {
        "Yes": function () {
            // ... do stuff
        },
        "No": function () {
            // do.. nothing? up to you.
        }
    } 
}
```

You'll see here that there are two functions defined, but none actually get executed. The `displayConfirm` function would have to construct a dialog box (in whichever way) and then create buttons, using those functions as the click handlers (or at least, calling them from the click handler).

Comment: Unfortunately even your code wouldn;t work. There is no blocking/waiting. I guess I am amazed that this simple type of function is not more extensive in the Browsers. Yet they have confirm() and alert() but no way to customize them a bit. I guess like everyone else I am stuck with canned confirm() or start rewriting ...ughhh

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible. You'll have to use an event driven custom dialog solution, or stick with the browsers default confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this w/o changing your calls. No custom code can stop execution like the `confirm` box can. Any solution will require editing code to an event model.

Answer (score -4):

As others have mentioned you can't do it directly, but I managed to do it in a round about way. Assuming like me you have a HTML button which submits a form, and want that button to have a jQuery modal dialog...

1. add an onclick event to the HTML button
2. make the onlick event open a jQueryUI dialog, and have the onclick event return false to cancel the button's default action
3. On your jQueryUI dialog, get the Yes/Ok button to remove the onclick event from the button in step 1, and then call then trigger the button to fire the click event

Comment: what button are you talking about? The one is a `confirm` dialog doesn't have an `onclick` event.

Comment: Uhh... what? So, your suggestion is to 1) create a button 2) overwrite its default behavior (which there is none) with an onclick attribute 3) find the element in javascript 4) remove its onclick attribute and replace it add some other event handler, that 5) calls the original event handler (which does nothing but return false)? Not only is this extremely long-winded, it doesn't achieve any blocking like what the asker desired, _and_ it probably doesn't work (if you add an onclick handler as a string, well, you can't call a string)

Comment: Why do you think I'm not calm? I'm trying to 1) understand your suggestion per se, as my current understanding suggests this answer is kinda long-winded 2) understand how it answers the question, as it seems to me it doesn't. Can you refute any of my prior points, or why you think the straight approach to just attach an event handler from javascript doesn't achieve the same effect as adding an extra temporary event handler that doesn't do anything but try to prevent the default action?

Comment: I think a code sample would clarify most of my doubts; can you post a code sample of what you mean by your suggestions? Most notably, I can't see any behavior that would prevent execution of further code in the same function, which is what the asker means by "replace `confirm`

Comment: I _am_ saying "uhh... what?" and I want something to cover. I don't know how that indicates I'm angry. If this has worked for you, either you had a different problem than the asker, or I'm misunderstanding your suggestion, or I'm misunderstanding the asker's problem (and so do three other answers). If it's the first one, then this answer doesn't belong here. If it's either of the latter two, can you correct my misunderstanding, or at least say which of these is true?

Comment: Or I could just leave your answer downvoted without further explanation, and leave you wondering. I don't know if that's what you want, but if it were my answer, I would want to know why some other person thinks I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm willing to apologise for saying "uhh... what?" if that's what angered you, but my point still stands; you're not answering your question, and I don't understand what you're trying to do or what does it solve. I still want to hear from you about the latter.